# Strategy to create many tables and charts from simple but large data (census)

Tags: java, jdbc, statistics, business-intelligence

Our task is to create many statistical analyses from census data (much data but easy analysis - mostly (sub)sums of data). The analyses are to be represented as tables and charts (in web - 2 languages - and pdf)
Lets assume the problem of storing the data is solved (SQL, good structure). The web-application (GWT) and Pdf (iText) Software is mostly done. We "only" have to change the data-backend.

what is a good strategy to efficiently create those analysis and there representations (tables, charts)?
two different ways come to my mind:

- simple java programming: jdbc or jpa, jfreechart (here we have experience, boring programming)
- bi tools birt, jasper, pentaho, palo... (learning to use them, boring pointing and clicking)

but is there probably a third way? a way between those 2: using the bi tool's apis to program the reports?? 
Is it worth to learn using a bi tool (i think with it, its much easier to create additional reports or adjust existing ones?)
What do you think?

Answer (score 2):

I've been in a similar situation recently. I've evaluated Pentaho BI server, so my remarks are based on that:

Pros of a custom system implemented in Java:

- Possibility to exactly customise according to user needs
- No need for [star schema](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_schema) (Pentaho analytics only works on star schemas! Pentaho reporting does not need a star schema, it can work by simple SQL statements)
- Due to not needing a star schema, you can integrate is easier with the rest of the system. By that I mean that you can reuse existing data sources. Also, by having a self-made UI, you can easily integrate it into the rest of the enterprise infrastructure (web portals, etc.)
- Speed: custom SQL tuning, custom UI that is fast for your dataset, etc.

Pros of using a ready-made solution (eg. Pentaho BI Server):

- After initial setup, even non technical users can create new analytics or modify existing ones. Easy exporting to excel, pdf, etc.
- Pentaho comes with many supporting tools (ETL tool to import data, scheduler to create reports periodaically, etc.). It would be a huge cost to re-implement all these. Also, the new Pentaho server has a dashboard feature, which means you can have a screen with charts and tables that updates as new data is coming in.
- If you can settle with the features and need no extra customization, deployment time is only a fraction of what it takes to develop new software.

Pentaho has extensive Java based APIs, you can create reports entirely in Java code, etc. Most of the core is open source, AFAIK only those parts are closed source which are in the Enterprise server (dashboard, analytics view, etc.)

As far as I know in case of Pentaho, there are APIs for the following:

- Create and modify reports, generate reports in various formats
- Access the scheduler
- Create custom widgets for the Dashboard
- Access the OLAP engine (eg. create an MDX expression and get the results)
- Since the BI server is a Spring container, more or less you can integrate it as any spring app (eg. you can access the Spring Security settings and plugin in your custom enterprise security, etc.)

Though not an API, there are ways to integrate Pentaho's web based report viewer into other web applications (the easiest way is to have a IFRAME and customize the report using URL parameters)

Comment: thx, the part about Java based APIs in BI-Solutions is the most important one for me, because i have to integrate the reports and output into an (web)application. are most/all of mentioned os-bi solutions easy to integrate in existing java aps?

Comment: I've only evaluated Pentaho, added some integration points to the above post.

Answer (score 1):

You might have a look to [icCube](http://www.icCube.com) :

- JAVA based for the back-end
- easy to create a cube model from your SQL data structure
- front end (charts) is made of pure Javascript API ([www](http://www.iccube.com/support/documentation/viz/viz/doc/vizTutorials.html), [www](http://demo3.iccube.com/icCube/doc/tutorial/ic3report-tutorial.html?ic3demo))
- possibility to use your own charting library

No point and click would be required I guess. Once setup, you would have great potential for providing analysis that goes beyond simple reporting (e.g., [histogram comparison](http://demo3.iccube.com/icCube/doc/tutorial/ic3report-tutorial.html?ic3demo&ic3reportName=Histogram)).